# Cannot Render Drawer Page React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So this is the case, i have login page when the state is before login it will render Login button but when is after login it will render drawer page but the problem drawerpage is not a component right ? because you get drawer page from drawernavigator , so what should i do here ? here is my code below

this is the render case

```
   import DrawerRoute from './DrawerRoute';
 _renderContent() {

    switch(this.state.displayType) {

      case 'before_login' :
        return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
          onPress={(this._showADLogin.bind(this))}>
          <Text style={{color : 'black'}}>Login Sekarang</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      case 'login' :
        // In fact we care if it successfully redirect to the URI, because
        // we alread have the access_token after successfully logged in.
        // set `hideAfterLogin` to `true` so that it won't display an error page.
        return [
          <ADLoginView
            key="webview"
            hideAfterLogin={true}
            style={{flex :1}}
            needLogout={this.state.shouldLogout}
            context={ADContext}
            onURLChange={this._onURLChange.bind(this)}
            onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess.bind(this)}/>]
      case 'after_login' :

      return [
          <DrawerRoute/>
      ]
```

and here is my DrawerRouter

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import FormCuti from './FormCuti';
    import FormLogin from './FormLogin';
    import DrawerMenu from './DrawerMenu';
    import NavigationReplace from './NavigationReplace';
    import {StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';



 const MainDrawer = StackNavigator ({
    FormLogin : {screen : FormLogin},
    FormCuti : {screen : FormCuti},
    NavigationReplace : {screen : NavigationReplace}
   // ScreenCuti : {screen : ScreenCuti}
 });
 const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main : {screen : MainDrawer}
  },
  {
    contentComponent: DrawerMenu,
    drawerWidth: 200
  }
);


export default Drawer;
```

can anyone give me inspiration here since DrawerRoute is not react component but a drawernavigator.

Answer (score 0):

You must use return component with "()". In your code change all "[]" with "()".

Use return like this :

```
return (<DrawerRoute/>);
```

Comment: no i dont think thats the problem, the problem is i try to render DrawerNavigator which is not a React Component, and now the question is how can i render it ?

Comment: because when i use another screen as return, like Form3 it will works